# 2 certificates into a PDF file with iText 7.0.2 for .NET

Tags: c#, certificate, itext7

I'm trying to put 2 certificates into a PDF file, but when I insert the second certificate, it invalidate my first. I'm using Itextsharp 7.02

```
protected internal virtual void Sign(string criador, int pagina, String src, String name, String dest, X509Certificate[] chain, ICipherParameters pk, String digestAlgorithm, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location, Rectangle rectangleForNewField, bool setReuseAppearance, bool isAppendMode)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileStream(dest,     FileMode.Create), isAppendMode);
    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance().
           SetSignatureCreator(criador).
           SetReason(reason).
           SetLocation(location).
           SetReuseAppearance(setReuseAppearance).
           SetPageNumber(pagina).
           SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
    if (rectangleForNewField != null)
    {
        appearance.SetPageRect(rectangleForNewField);
    }
    signer.SetFieldName(name);

    // Creating the signature
    IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk,  digestAlgorithm);
    signer.SignDetached(pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
}
```

and I'm calling this method:

```
Sign("teste", 2, src, "nomeDoCampo", "dest", chain[], pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, PdfSigner.NOT_CERTIFIED, "razao", "local", rect, false, true);
```

Comment: By 2 *certificates* do you happen to mean 2 *signatures*?

Comment: That's it. I have a document that needs been certificate by 2,3,4 or 5 certificates. Like Mayor and lawyer and others. They need make this in diferents moments but when I push the second certificate It invalidated the first. How do I do this without invalidated?

Comment: First of all, you need to use append mode, but you already appear to do so. For further analysis of the issue, you need to share a copy of a file signed once ok and a copy of that file signed a second time invalidating the first signature.